# How can I get the reference id of a foreign key field of a JPA entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In an application using spring boot using JPA, suppose I have two entities (`Author` and `Post`) like this:

```
@Entity
public class Author
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class Post
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;
}
```

Please note that, the `fetch` setting of the `@ManyToOne` annotation on `Author` field is `LAZY`. Now suppose I have fetched a `Post` entity by id from related `JPARepository<Post,Integer>` using `findById()`, all relevant field values should be available, right? If I want *just* the `author_id` of this `post`, how can I get it without making another database call? Accessing with `post.getAuthor()` makes another call, and I want to avoid it. I want just the `author_id`.

Apologies for the poorly stated question; but can't find good one.

P.S.

- Spring/JPA/Java noob here.
- May be the question is already answered elsewhere; but could not find one.
- Please don't suggest `EAGER` loading.

Comment: What about using jpa query method? you can read about that here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query and also have a look at query creation with property expressions https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 3):

You can save the `author_id` right in the entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Author.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Integer authorId;
```

Also you can have both fields: `authorId` and `author` with the same `JoinColumn`, but in this case you have to mark one of them with `insertable=false` and `updatable =false`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Anton Kozub for the answer/clue. Although I could not make it working (may be he showed it partially), but I got a clue and finally made this in the `Post` table:

```
@Entity
public class Post
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "author_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Integer authorId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to block that. Better use EAGER loading.
But if you want to get only Post and id of Author, I'll suggest to use nativeQuery.

```
public interface PostAuthorProjection {

   Integer getId();

   Integer getAuthorId();

}
```

Repository

```
public interface PostRepo extends CrudRepository<Post, Integer> {

   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select p.id, p.author_id from post p where p.id = ?1")
   PostAuthorProjection findPostById(Integer id);
}
```

That's all
use `getAuthorId()` to get author.id.
Hope it will helpful.